# Minimum of a function connected to permutations weighing by inverse squares

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question (may be of classical number theory and combinatorics) arose during my study, please help me

Let $ K,T$ be two natural numbers such that, $1\leq T\leq K!$.
Consider the set, $S=\{f:\{1,2,...,K\}\to\{1,2,...,K\}\,|\,\mbox {$f$ is bijective}\}$ 
Then find the $T$-th minimum value  of the set $$B=\Big\{\sum_{n=1}^K\frac{g(n)}{n^2}\,\Big|\,g\in S\Big\}$$
(i.e., after arranging the elements of $B$ in ascending order, what is the T-th value?)

Can any one help me to find out the solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have attempted to find a title reflecting the issue. Feel free to modify it.

Comment: @user No, why would the lexicographic order work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it arose during my study"? The lack of condition on $T,K$ is suspicious.

Comment: The cardinality of B is K!. We have arrange those values in ascending order.

Comment: @user $\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{9}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{1}{25} > \frac{2}{1}+\frac{4}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{5}{25}$.  I for one see no reason why this question should have a concise answer in full generality.

Comment: Can you take a numerical example (obtained for example through a computer program) with low values of $K,T$ in order to clarify your question ?

Comment: Yes, following is the calculated Sum over all possible permutations for K=4

Answer (score 0):

Following is the calculated sums over all possible permutations for K=4
[image: See this pic]

This may help others to predict hypothesis regarding the problem

Comment: A trivial remark: For every permutation where $g(k)<g(k+q)$, flipping these two will increase the sum. e.g. $B(4,1,2,3)<B(4,3,2,1)$ etc.